# Add Title Product to After tab-description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Support add title auto in tab description woocom

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'devvn_custom_remove_tabs', 98 );
function devvn_custom_remove_tabs( $tabs ){
    if(is_product()){
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );
        $tabs['description']['title'] = __('Detail Product','woocommerce');
        $tabs['description']['callback'] = 'devvn_custom_description_tab_content';
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

----Ex Title Product is ABC
----I want auto set: Detail Product ABC
----Can Use:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

----Help add code to title.

Comment: Your question content is not understandable. You should use Google Translate.

Comment: $tabs['description']['title'] = sprintf( __( 'Detail Product %s', 'woocommerce' ), $product->get_title() );

Comment: Yes, I want to add the product title after this (Detail Product).
Specifically: Detail Product + product title.
The above code I am using.